# Positioning a div using jQuery offfset - Code works but only for one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, offset

I am trying to set the position of a div using CSS 'top' based on the offset position of another element.  This element is not adjacent or a parent/child therefore I have to use javascrip/jQuery.

I came across the following code which worked perfect for my first element (with offset position retrieved from 'mark2' and position properly set for 'side2' however when I replicate the code for 'mark3' and 'side3' respectfully it does not work.  Either block of code works in isolation but seem to conflict with each other.  I renamed all variables and still there is a conflict.

If anyone can shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function(event) {
    //Get
    var p = $("#mark2");
    var something = p.offset();

    //set
    $("#side2").css('top', something.top+'px');

    };

    window.onresize = function(event) {
    //Get
    var p = $("#mark2");
    var something = p.offset();

    //set
    $("#side2").css('top', something.top+'px');

    };
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function(event) {
    //Get
    var y = $("#mark3");
    var somethingelse = y.offset();

    //set
    $("#side3").css('top', somethingelse.top+'px');

    };

    window.onresize = function(event) {
    //Get
    var y = $("#mark3");
    var somethingelse = y.offset();

    //set
    $("#side3").css('top', somethingelse.top+'px');

    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the = way of setting an event listener it override the previous event listener. The best way to fix this is using a callback function in a jquery event like so:

```
$(window).on('load', function (event) {
  // Code goes here
});

$(window).on('resize', function (event) {
  // Code goes here
});
```

That should allow more than one event listener per event.

Comment: Worked like a charm! And to think of all the times I had 'conflicting' jQuery....

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you do `window.onload = something`, you're overwriting that property.

You need an event handler, and as you're using jQuery

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    var p         = $("#mark2");
    var something = p.offset();

    $("#side2").css('top', something.top + 'px');


    var y             = $("#mark3");
    var somethingelse = y.offset();

    $("#side3").css('top', somethingelse.top+'px');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the added on  load/resize to get rid of redundant code!